# How to implement this time picker UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am been trying to implement this time picker UI. I used SingleChildScrollView() to implement the scrolling but I am not getting it how to retrieve the data which user selects.

I used NotificationListener() but it is only notifying me where user is starting and ending the scrolling.

I want to retrieve the value where user stops. How to do that ? Click link to view UI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmdNB.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try `ListWheelScrollView` class which has more appropriate design for this case and provides a callback `onSelectedItemChanged`. So you can retrieve desired value from it.
This widget works like a ListView with focused sections and also have some nice features for customization.